# Why hashing is required if i am using my own secret key?

Tags: java, encryption, aes, encryption-symmetric

Why hashing is required if i am using my own secret key ? i found that everywhere it is done as shown below

```
        key = myKey.getBytes("UTF-8");
        sha = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
        key = sha.digest(key);
        key = Arrays.copyOf(key, 16);
        secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
```

Can some one explain me what is the benefit of hashing here ?

Comment: It's just a reliable and secure way of getting a 16-byte key from a larger one.

Comment: `key` can't be a properly chosen key, since you're using UTF-8 to encode it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because in your case AES requires a 128 bit key so to build it up it need 16 bytes. How to get those 16 bytes? The most common way is to hash your user password and grab the first 16 bytes of the hash. Doing this will ensure that the AES algorithm will always receive a proper 16 bytes key.

Thanks to the hashing algorithm even short passwords such as "123456" or "god" will be transformed to a fixed length 20 byte hash

Comment: In my case i am generating the 128 bits secret key using unix and writing it to a file using following command **dd if=/dev/urandom of=/data/myfolder/key/aeskey.txt bs=16 count=1**. can i directly read the key from file for encryptiopn/decryption or i need to do hashing after reading it.

Comment: in your case there's no reason to do it. Hashing doesn't make your key stronger or any weaker (in terms of entropy). It's just a one-way transformation. /dev/urandom is a good entropy source and as long the underlying PRNG is good you can directly feed the AES with its outcome.

Comment: you're welcome! +1 to you for using /dev/urandom and not the classic rand(time(0));